# How can a thread force execution of a function in the context of another existing thread?

Tags: linux, delphi

In a Delphi/Linux program, let's say I have two running threads, ThreadA and ThreadB. At some point in time ThreadB need to make ThreadA execute a function and block until the function returns.

In Delphi, we have TThread.Synchronize which does the work, but only when ThreadA is the main thread.

Any idea? I use Delphi but an answer with C code is also welcome.

Comment: You could create a thread which you pass over an anonymous method that calls that function in question. Then you do a WaitFor on the just started thread.

Comment: And if both threads remain alive before and after, you can wait on any other sync object like a `TEvent` shared between the threads.  How you manage sharing the event, the method reference, etc, will depend on how your program is designed.  If the threads have visibility of each other they can do this directly but if they're hidden from each other then you could use a third "manager" thread to marshal the method reference and sync object, etc.  Lots of ways to slice this - hard to pick a single example that would work in all cases.

Comment: "*if both threads remain alive before and after, you can wait on any other sync object like a `TEvent` shared between the threads*" - which is exactly how `TThread.Synchronize()` works. It puts the requested function into a queue, along with a waitable object, and then waits for the object to be signaled. The main thread periodically checks the queue for items, calling their functions and signaling their objects.

Comment: @DelphiCoder The threads are already created and running. I don't want one more thread. I need the TThread.Synchronize feature but for threads which are not the main thread.

Comment: Would it be a problem to start a new one? Just not wanting can make things complicated instead of doing it the possibly easiest way.

Comment: @DelphiCoder creating a new thread just to call a function, while the creator blocks on the new thread, is a complete waste of a thread, you may as well have the creator call the function directly. Unless the function *absolutely must* be run in a different thread context.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you have a point here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this the threads will have to co-operate, there's no mechanism to trigger events across threads.  However if you are prepared to implement such a mechanism it's not difficult to do, and of course you can look at the source code for `TThread.Synchronize` for tips.

Borrowing from the source for `TThread.Syncrhonize` I have come up with the following.  You will have to have the co-operating threads check their queues as part of their main loops - which is of course how `TThread.Synchronize` works.

The following code is based on code we use in production - my apologies if there are comments or references to items not in the unit.  There is no mechanism to provide a result of the function, but that could be resolved with using different calling templates (so the result type is known).  I have allowed for a Result `TObject` (even though there's no way to know what that should be currently) so that multi-valued results can be returned if needed.

There's no windows specific code in the following, so it *should* work on Linux as you requested.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses  Classes, SyncObjs, Generics.Collections;

  type
  TQueuedCallback = class(TObject)
  protected
    _pEvent:            TEvent;
    _pResult:           TObject;
    _fnMethod:          TThreadMethod;
    _fnProcedure:       TThreadProcedure;

  public

    property  Event: TEvent read _pEvent write _pEvent;
    property  Result: TObject read _pResult write _pResult;
    property  Method: TThreadMethod read _fnMethod write _fnMethod;
    property  Proc: TThreadProcedure read _fnProcedure write _fnProcedure;

  end;

  TQueueableThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    _pCSLock:           TCriticalSection;
    _pQueuedCalls:      TList<TQueuedCallback>;
    _haSignals:         THandleObjectArray;
    _pQueueEvent:       TEvent;
    _pStopEvent:        TEvent;
    _dwMaxWait:         Cardinal;

    procedure _DoWork(nEventIndex: Integer); virtual; abstract;   // where th thread does it's work
    procedure _ExecuteQueued(blAll: Boolean = False); virtual;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure AfterConstruction(); override;
    procedure Execute(); override;
    procedure QueueProcedure(fnMethod: TThreadMethod); overload; virtual;
    procedure QueueProcedure(fnProcedure: TThreadProcedure); overload; virtual;
    procedure QueueProcedureAndWait(fnMethod: TThreadMethod); overload; virtual;
    procedure QueueProcedureAndWait(fnProcedure: TThreadProcedure); overload; virtual;
    function  QueueProcedureAndWaitForResult(fnMethod: TThreadMethod): TObject; overload; virtual;
    function  QueueProcedureAndWaitForResult(fnProcedure: TThreadProcedure): TObject; overload; virtual;

  end;

implementation

uses  SysUtils;

  { TQueueableThread }

  procedure TQueueableThread._ExecuteQueued(blAll: Boolean);
  begin
    repeat
      Self._pCSLock.Enter();
      if(Self._pQueuedCalls.Count>0) then
      begin
        if(Assigned(Self._pQueuedCalls.Items[0].Method)) then
          Self._pQueuedCalls.Items[0].Method()
        else if(Assigned(Self._pQueuedCalls.Items[0].Proc)) then
          Self._pQueuedCalls.Items[0].Proc();
        // No mechanism for supplying a result ...
        if(Self._pQueuedCalls.Items[0]._pEvent<>nil) then
          Self._pQueuedCalls.Items[0]._pEvent.SetEvent()
        else
          Self._pQueuedCalls.Items[0].Free;
        Self._pQueuedCalls.Delete(0);
      end;
      blAll:=(blAll And (Self._pQueuedCalls.Count>0));
      Self._pCSLock.Leave();
    until not blAll;
  end;

  destructor TQueueableThread.Destroy;
  begin
    if(Self._pQueuedCalls<>nil) then
    begin
      while(Self._pQueuedCalls.Count>0) do
      begin
        if(Self._pQueuedCalls.Items[0].Event<>nil) then
          Self._pQueuedCalls.Items[0].Event.SetEvent()
        else
          Self._pQueuedCalls.Items[0].Free();
        Self._pQueuedCalls.Delete(0);
      end;
      FreeAndNil(Self._pQueuedCalls);
    end;
    FreeAndNil(Self._pQueueEvent);
    FreeAndNil(Self._pStopEvent);
    FreeAndNil(Self._pCSLock);
    inherited;
  end;

  procedure TQueueableThread.AfterConstruction();
  begin
    inherited;
    Self._pCSLock:=TCriticalSection.Create();
    Self._pQueuedCalls:=TList<TQueuedCallback>.Create();
    SetLength(Self._haSignals, 2);
    Self._pQueueEvent:=TEvent.Create();
    Self._haSignals[0]:=Self._pQueueEvent;
    Self._pStopEvent:=TEvent.Create();
    Self._haSignals[1]:=Self._pStopEvent;
    Self._dwMaxWait:=30000;
  end;

  procedure TQueueableThread.Execute();
  var
    dwWaitResult:       TWaitResult;
    nEventIndex:        Integer;
    nLoop:              Integer;
    pSignalled:         THandleObject;
  begin
    while(not Self.Terminated) do
    begin
      //LogThreadMessage(GetCurrentThreadId(), Self.ClassType, Format('WaitingFor: %u', [Self._MaxWaitTime]));
      dwWaitResult:=THandleObject.WaitForMultiple(Self._haSignals, Self._dwMaxWait, False, pSignalled);
      //LogThreadMessage(GetCurrentThreadId(), Self.ClassType, Format('WaitForMultipleObjects Result: %u', [dwWaitResult]));
      if(dwWaitResult=wrError) then
        Self.Terminate;
      if not Self.Terminated then
      begin
        if(pSignalled=Self._pQueueEvent) then
        begin
          Self._ExecuteQueued(True);
          Self._pQueueEvent.ResetEvent();
        end
        else if(pSignalled=Self._pStopEvent) then
          Self.Terminate()
        else
        begin
          nEventIndex:=-2;
          if(dwWaitResult=wrTimeout) then
            nEventIndex:=-1
          else
          begin
            nLoop:=0;
            while( (nEventIndex<0) And (nLoop<Length(Self._haSignals)) ) do
            begin
              if(Self._haSignals[nLoop]=pSignalled) then
                nEventIndex:=nLoop
              else
                Inc(nLoop);
            end;
            if(nEventIndex>-2) then
            begin
              try
                Self._DoWork(nEventIndex);
              except
                on e: Exception do
                  // error handling
              end;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  procedure TQueueableThread.QueueProcedure(fnMethod: TThreadMethod);
  var
    pQueue:             TQueuedCallback;
  begin
    if(Assigned(fnMethod)) then
    begin
      Self._pCSLock.Enter();
      pQueue:=TQueuedCallback.Create();
      pQueue.Method:=fnMethod;
      Self._pQueuedCalls.Add(pQueue);
      Self._pQueueEvent.SetEvent();
      Self._pCSLock.Leave();
    end;
  end;

  procedure TQueueableThread.QueueProcedure(fnProcedure: TThreadProcedure);
  var
    pQueue:             TQueuedCallback;
  begin
    if(Assigned(fnProcedure)) then
    begin
      Self._pCSLock.Enter();
      pQueue:=TQueuedCallback.Create();
      pQueue.Proc:=fnProcedure;
      Self._pQueuedCalls.Add(pQueue);
      Self._pQueueEvent.SetEvent();
      Self._pCSLock.Leave();
    end;
  end;

  procedure TQueueableThread.QueueProcedureAndWait(fnMethod: TThreadMethod);
  var
    pQueue:             TQueuedCallback;
  begin
    if(Assigned(fnMethod)) then
    begin
      Self._pCSLock.Enter();
      pQueue:=TQueuedCallback.Create();
      pQueue.Method:=fnMethod;
      pQueue.Event:=TEvent.Create();
      Self._pQueuedCalls.Add(pQueue);
      Self._pQueueEvent.SetEvent();
      Self._pCSLock.Leave();
      pQueue._pEvent.WaitFor(INFINITE);
      FreeAndNil(pQueue._pEvent);
      FreeAndNil(pQueue);
    end;
  end;

  procedure TQueueableThread.QueueProcedureAndWait(fnProcedure: TThreadProcedure);
  var
    pQueue:             TQueuedCallback;
  begin
    if(Assigned(fnPRocedure)) then
    begin
      Self._pCSLock.Enter();
      pQueue:=TQueuedCallback.Create();
      pQueue.Proc:=fnProcedure;
      pQueue.Event:=TEvent.Create();
      Self._pQueuedCalls.Add(pQueue);
      Self._pQueueEvent.SetEvent();
      Self._pCSLock.Leave();
      pQueue._pEvent.WaitFor(INFINITE);
      FreeAndNil(pQueue._pEvent);
      FreeAndNil(pQueue);
    end;
  end;

  function  TQueueableThread.QueueProcedureAndWaitForResult(fnMethod: TThreadMethod): TObject;
  var
    pQueue:             TQueuedCallback;
  begin
    Result:=nil;
    if(Assigned(fnMethod)) then
    begin
      Self._pCSLock.Enter();
      pQueue:=TQueuedCallback.Create();
      pQueue.Method:=fnMethod;
      pQueue.Event:=TEvent.Create();
      Self._pQueuedCalls.Add(pQueue);
      Self._pQueueEvent.SetEvent();
      Self._pCSLock.Leave();
      pQueue._pEvent.WaitFor(INFINITE);
      Result:=pQueue._pResult;
      FreeAndNil(pQueue._pEvent);
      FreeAndNil(pQueue);
    end;
  end;

  function  TQueueableThread.QueueProcedureAndWaitForResult(fnProcedure: TThreadProcedure): TObject;
  var
    pQueue:             TQueuedCallback;
  begin
    Result:=nil;
    if(Assigned(fnProcedure)) then
    begin
      Self._pCSLock.Enter();
      pQueue:=TQueuedCallback.Create();
      pQueue.Proc:=fnProcedure;
      pQueue.Event:=TEvent.Create();
      Self._pQueuedCalls.Add(pQueue);
      Self._pQueueEvent.SetEvent();
      Self._pCSLock.Leave();
      pQueue._pEvent.WaitFor(INFINITE);
      Result:=pQueue._pResult;
      FreeAndNil(pQueue._pEvent);
      FreeAndNil(pQueue);
    end;
  end;

end.
```

You could have inherited classes of `TQueuedCallback` that use a specific calling template, and this would be one way to identify the return value